# jquery ui theme api

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-ui-theme

**EDIT: 1**

The following does not work, even after clearing browser cache:

```
.ui-state-hover {background-image:none;background-color:red;color:red;padding:50px;margin:50px;}
```

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

Using [jquery's ui theme api](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/API), I am trying to change the hover effect of jquery-ui-tabs:

```
.ui-state-hover {background-color:red;color:red;padding:50px;}
```

Here is the full script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
        });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .ui-state-hover {background-color:red;color:red;padding:50px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, </p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus </p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. </p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But it does not seem to work.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to be more specific because ".ui-state-default" with additional class hierarchy in the external css overrides your css.

change `.ui-state-default {background:red;color:red;padding:50px;}` to

```
#tabs .ui-state-default {background:red;color:red;padding:50px;}
```

and `background:red` instead of `background-color:red` because there is an background image

see demo http://jsfiddle.net/aX5c9/

Comment: Shouldn't the local CSS _always_ override an external css? I though thats the whole point of _cascading_ style sheets.

Comment: @ZeissS: you are right. actually here what happens is there are additional class hierarchy. if we use #tabs there it will be the most specific else we need to override each class hierarchy in the external css. say .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default { background:red;color:red;padding:50px; } will change the background but won't change padding because it follows another hierarchy. so when you develop website from another css-static-framework it is better to be specific

Answer (score 1):

I guest it's 'ui-state-hover' class?

Comment: You beat me to it.  I corrected that, but it made no difference.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I believe that it's `.ui-state-hover`, not `ui-widget-hover`. Secondly, it looks like the original theme is using a background image, not a color:

```
.ui-state-hover .ui-icon, .ui-state-focus .ui-icon {background-image: url(images/ui-icons_454545_256x240.png); }
```

So if you want to change the background, you'll need to either use a different image, or set `background-image: none;` in addition to `background-color`.

Check out this JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Uce8S/

You need to do `.ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover` for tab headers.

Comment: The following does not work: .ui-state-hover {background-image:none;background-color:red;color:red;padding:50px;margin:50px;}